# How do I embed a script in HTML doc to dynamically retrieve and display content from external URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a responsive email template (html) that contains a static photo gallery. I'm looking to replace the static content with code that dynamically retrieves the active office listings from my real estate business website (under the 'our listings' section here: https://mfox.golyon.com/offices/roseville), and displays a thumbnail for each one instead. The thumbnails should be clickable and would link to the full property listing detail on the business page.

I have not worked towards a solution yet because I am trying to determine if the functionality I desire is possible. If embedded javascript is required, do I need a framework like React? One potential solution I came across was the following syntax with jQuery:

```
    $('body').load( url,[data],[callback] );
```

Here is a link to my codepen where the full code can be viewed: https://codepen.io/mercury715/project/editor/DBQPae

I don't expect anyone to solve this for me, but pointing me in the right direction where I can conduct additional research would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You cannot run JavaScript in email.

Comment: Learn about CORS and the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @SLaks won't matter in an email

Comment: If you just want to show images from a domain you control (say you own `example.com`), you can have `<a href="http://example.com/listing1><img src=http://example.com/image1.png></a>` elements, then have the server dynamically decide what image is served when it gets a request for `image1.png` (and what URL `/listing1` redirects to), depending on your latest listings. Generalize this to `image2.png`, etc. as well.

Comment: apsillers' approach will work if you want users opening the same email some time later to see the latest images meaning they will see different images each time they open the email. You'd also have to make the links similarly adaptive. If instead you want the links to be unique and persistent, you'll actually need to swap out the links to the latest whenever you send the email. This is usually done with a server-side script (e.g. PHP) that auto-sends the email.